# Android Browser with fullscreen and autoplay support

Tags: android, browser, fullscreen, autoplay

i'm building a little project with a Android box (MINIX Neo X5 Mini, Android 4.2.2). I'm searching for a browser that supports fullscreen (kiosk mode) and the autoplay tag of embedded youtube videos. The box must start automatically, no user interaction should be required.

**Chrome for Android** does well the autoplay of the youtube videos (with activatet #disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback in the chrome://flags), but does not support the fullscreen.

**Firefox for Android** (latest version) has a great fullscreen extension which works great but im not able to get running the autoplay youtube video.

Does anyone know if there is a android browser that supports both requirements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about UC browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Dolphin-Browser for Android because it fitted best my needs.